# fclose(): Argument #1 ($stream) must be of type resource, bool given

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, window

I just restart my laravel 8.0 project and I got this below error, please what could be wrong, this happens anytime I run "PHP artisan serve"

```
   TypeError

  fclose(): Argument #1 ($stream) must be of type resource, bool given

  at C:\Users\owner\Laravel-App\test-app\vendor\symfony\process\Pipes\WindowsPip
es.php:74
     70▕                         fclose($this->lockHandles[$pipe]);
     71▕                     }
     72▕                     $this->lockHandles[$pipe] = $h;
     73▕
  ➜  74▕                     if (!fclose(fopen($file, 'w')) || !$h = fopen($file
, 'r')) {
     75▕                         flock($this->lockHandles[$pipe], \LOCK_UN);
     76▕                         fclose($this->lockHandles[$pipe]);
     77▕                         unset($this->lockHandles[$pipe]);
     78▕                         continue 2;
       continue 2;

  1   C:\Users\owner\Laravel-App\test-app\vendor\symfony\process\Pipes\WindowsPi
pes.php:74
      fclose()

  2   C:\Users\owner\Laravel-App\test-app\vendor\symfony\process\Process.php:130
4
      Symfony\Component\Process\Pipes\WindowsPipes::__construct()
```

Comment: Not sure about laravel but i dont think you can have the fopen inside of the close like that, don't you need the handle to have its own var? like this: `$fopen = fopen($file, 'w');` then use `if (!fclose($fopen) || !$h = fopen($file, 'r'))` maybe?

Comment: thank you for replying when i uesd  $fopen = fopen($file, 'w');

                    if (!$fopen || !$h = fopen($file, 'r')) it works but giving another error "404
NOT FOUND"

Comment: Maybe your `$file` doesn't exist? And before you had it like this: `if (!fclose($fopen) || !$h = fopen($file, 'r'))` NOT like this `if (!$fopen || !$h = fopen($file, 'r'))`. Not sure if that could have something todo with it.

Comment: Have you tried restarting your machine?

Comment: i have treid restarting and gettting those error

Comment: Please share more details - how is this related to [tag:composer-php] or [tag:window]?

Comment: i really dont know why this is affecting  my whole project on this machine, when ever i run anything it gives that error, even though i run "composer update, it gives this error

Answer (score 23):

You can open the task manager then look for CLI (with the php logo) background process, if you find it then kill task

Answer (score 6):

Don't **restart**, don't **uninstall**, don't **panic** !

If you are on **Windows Machine** then follow these below step :

1. Click the **Start** charm.
2. Type **cmd**, right-click the Command Prompt tile, and then click **Run as administrator**.
3. Type `tasklist /v | find "php"` press enter and find the PID of php.exe
4. Kill the process by `taskkill /PID <PID> /F`
5. You are done.

Answer (score 4):

I had another Laravel application running that I forgot about (in the terminal of another IDE).  Ctl + C (killing) that allowed me to get past this error msg.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error today and applied all the solutions but this resolved my error.

1. Un-install the composer.
2. Restart your machine
3. Install the composer

Answer (score 0):

First run `composer install` before trying to start the dev server using `php artisan serve`. You might also have to generate the key using `php artisan key:generate` incase the app starts with errors.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered same issues I hope this solution help someone else:

```
1. Delete the **vendor** folder/directory of the project
2. run **"composer install"** to install packages.
```

That fixed my issues.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this issue by searching the process that was keeping open the file `sf_proc_00.err` within `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Temp` (the local Windows temp directory). Process Explorer or similar tools can be used for this. It was locked by `ssh.exe` (very likely launched by git). After killing the process, composer runs normally again.

Answer (score 0):

**Just Stop/Shoutdown Artisan Server**

**It's work for me**

Answer (score -1):

You should clear the config cache using `optimize:clear` command:

```
php artisan optimize:clear
```

Answer (score -1):

The solution is very easy, just do

```
php artisan config:clear
```

Then rerun

```
php artisan serve
```